# Using jQuery/TinySort to loop through highest -> lowest -> original order

Tags: jquery, sorting, toggle

The following is a simple sort which will sort from low to high.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('li').tsort();
});
```

I need a method that goes to high to low then to the orginal order when the button is pressed again.

Think of a table header columns on Wikipedia.

My original plan was to store a variable for the number of clicks. Is there a more elegant method using jQuery?

I'm having trouble understanding how TinySort remembers the original order but looking at the docs (http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) there seems to be a custom function to return the original order. Can anyone show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the 'original' parameter then you misunderstood. That one is a boolean and sorts in place if the selection is a subselection. (so this only works if you are sorting say 10 items in your list of 20 items, leaving the unsorted items in their original place).

What you want to do is first create a jQuery object to store the order.
Then sort but using a new jQuery object.
Then replace contents with the first one.

```
var $Parent = $('ul')
    ,$Original = $Parent.find('li')
    ,isSorted = false
    ,$Button = $('button').click(function() {
        if (isSorted) {
            $Original.appendTo($Parent);
            isSorted = false;
        } else {
            $Parent.find('li').tsort();
            isSorted = true;
        }
    });
```

I haven't tested the code, but that is the way I'd go about it. (oh.. this only works with a single unordered list)

gr

Ron

Comment: Ahh cool, thanks. Also I think there might be an error with your "sorting tables" example. When I click `add row` nothing seems to happen.